# Weighing probabilities into a polygon

Tags: data-visualization, clustering

I have a collection of 4-member probability vectors (essentially proportions over 4 mutually exclusive categories). Is there a method to represent this data as a cloud of points inside a square? If each of the values of the 4-tuple represents a weight towards one of the 4 edges, can we appropriately place each inside the 2D space?

What I am looking for is a method to plot data of the following sort:

```
1: 1 0 0 0
2: 0 1 0 0
3: 0.5 0.5 0 0
4: 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25
```

In the following fashion (sorry the bottom border got clipped)

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: The problem you discuss (representing 4d points as 2d points) is called **dimensionality reduction**.  Google or read wikipedia articles about the topic.

Comment: Thank you, user31264. I did my research, but I was wondering if there is a way to do this without losing information (i.e. having all 100% variance preserved in the modified dataset).

Comment: I afraid that is not possible. Suppose you have 4 points in vertices of a regular tetrahedron. Their mutual distances will be the same.  You cannot reproduce it at a plane.

Comment: Okay, a little more reading have clarified this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at **Multidimensional Scaling**. This will try to find the 2d projection that best preserves your distances. For obvious reasons, There is no lossless 4d to 2d projection.